# Get Stripe Customer ID on WordPress / WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm building an e-commerce website which is linked to a mobile app.

I would like to store the stripe customer id of a customer on WordPress after his purchase/subscription

Is it possible? How?

Comment: you probably needs to build a customer DB your self or if you are using woocommerce plugins to manage customer information, you might need to customize the plugins to allow you to update the customer info.

Comment: you can call an API when a new order is placed, get the customer id from user meta table

Comment: This is possible by using the field  : wp__stripe_customer_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the field : wp__stripe_customer_id